# What do we intuitively mean by embedding a manifold in an $n$-dimensional space?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

What do we intuitively mean by embedding a manifold in an $n$-dimensional space?
Also, why does a circle look so differently when is is embedded in $3$-space than $2$-space?

Comment: Do you have a picture of a circle in $3$-space where it looks very different than it does in $2$-space?

Comment: You can embed a circle into 3-space in many different ways. There's an entire field of mathematics which studies embeddings of circles into $\mathbb{R}$^3, called [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory)

Comment: I have been told that a circle embedded in 2-space has the normal circular structure while if you embed it in 3-space is a structure with knots. I also found this link :                                      https://www.quora.com/What-do-we-intuitively-mean-by-embedding-a-manifold-into-a-higher-dimensional-space-Can-you-give-some-examples

Comment: I see.  But a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can also look like a circle - it doesn't have to have "twists" or "knots".  The extra dimension just gives enough "room" for these things to exist.

Comment: @Shagnik So, it is just a possibility? So, embedding "structures" in n-dimensional spaces can have various outcomes of shapes? Mustn't be there uniqueness in the way that a structure(like a circle) is embedded in a space or is it free to bend and twist in the new ways that the extra dimensions of space allow it?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ So, what defines the precise way that a circle will be embedded in R^3? Also, this "freedom" is due to the extra degrees of freedom that the space allows the "structure"(here circle) to move in?

Comment: As @ಠ_ಠ pointed out, the field of knot theory studies all the different ways you can embed a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so there certainly is no uniqueness.  A (topological) circle can even look different in $\mathbb{R}^2$ - you can stretch it out in different directions.  Just think of all the things you could do with a rubber band lying on a desk!

Comment: Wow, I thank all of you for clarifying this to me

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ : Could I convince you to write $\mathbb R^3$ instead of $\mathbb R$^3? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I really haven't given much time to learn about how to write LaTex yet! But this is hardly the point here; I see no harm in writing R^3 in this context; everyone understand it because the conversation is not complex. But, sure!

Comment: When you embed a circle into $\Bbb{R}^3$ as a knot $K$, the fun topology studies the **complement** $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus K$. As a topological space $K$ is always just a circle, but the complements may become highly non-trivial (and non-homeomorphic for different embeddings).

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, when we say "embed $M$ in $\Bbb R^n$", we mean "Find a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ which, with the inherited topology / differential structure, is homeomorphic / diffeomorphic to $M$."